# Model is not reading from my Database (Entitity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework

I created simple MVC application with a database.
 
First I created a database, initialized the database, then I created a model from the database and the application worked..
Then I decide to load database with totaly different values (but the definitons of tables/fields stayed the same)..
After reloading the database my application does not shows any data from my DB. Using debugger I saw that my application cannot get any data from the table.
Worse - I noticed that additional to my database TestDB, the database explorer is showing TestDB.mdf1 database, with the same definitions as testDB.mdf but table is empty...

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult ShowQuestions() 
{ 
     TestDBEntities _db = new TestDBEntities(); // this is the database 
     ObjectSet<question> all_quest = _db.questions ;      // this is the table 
     foreach (var x in all_quest) 
     { 
               ..... // this part was never executed 
     } 

     return View(q_list); 
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create a totally new database, or simply change the data in the same database?  Is your database initializer to DropCreateAlways or DropCreateOnModelChanged?

Answer (score 0):

1- check the connection string in your MVC application (web.config). This will tell you which database is being used. Then go to this database and check if you have data in your tables.
If it's the wrong database, just amend the connection string.

2- If it's the correct database, but without data, just add data.
It may have been recreated by your ORM (who knows?).

3- What is the error you are getting? Or are you getting any error?

Comment: Thanks AndreCruz,
I have no idea how it happened, but the connection string did not point to my database. 
Now I fixed it and it is working.

Thanks

zalek